# Modifying a jquery zoom on mouseover script

Tags: jquery, zooming

I am using this zoom on hover script http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

I am trying to implement this into a gallery type page but the hover function seems to only work on the first image

```
<span class='zoom' id='ex1'>
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/y2qMsNn.jpg' width='555' height='320' alt='Daisy on the Ohoopee'/>
<p>Hover</p>
</span>
<span class='zoom' id='ex1'>
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/y2qMsNn.jpg' width='555' height='320' alt='Daisy on the Ohoopee'/>
<p>Hover</p>
</span>
<span class='zoom' id='ex1'>
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/y2qMsNn.jpg' width='555' height='320' alt='Daisy on the Ohoopee'/>
<p>Hover</p>
</span>
```

Heres a demo of my situation http://jsfiddle.net/drhbt/

How can I have the script give every image the zoom function?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: only one id per element per page.  change id=ex1 on second element to id=ex2 change id=ex1 on third element to id=ex3, or use classes such as class=ex1 class=ex1 class=ex1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't do a better test, but I changed the id to a class and it worked.

```
$('.zoom').zoom();
```

Comment: yes! i have just realized this after carter pointed it out above. thanks for all your help!